# how to make this program can accept the a word and h word but the h word is not repeatable

Tags: c, string

How to make this program can accept a word and h word but the h word can't be repeated. And if the string length of the x is bigger than the h print go else print no

i tried to make this but it can accept if i repeat the h word

```
scanf("%s\n",x);
scanf("%s",h);
y=strlen(x);
g=strlen(h);
if(strcmp(x,"a")>=0 && strcmp(x,"h")<=0&& y,g>0 && y,g<=999){
    if(strstr(x,o)!=0 && strstr(h,o)!=0){
    if(y>g){
        printf("go");
    }else{
        printf("no");
    }   
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show valid and invalid inputs. It's not very clear what you want as it is.

Comment: What do you believe `y,g` does?

Comment: the y,g is just for length of string. The maximum string length i want is 999

Comment: `y,g` means `g`, this may not be what you think.